# Two tables having same columns in both of them now need to add foreign key on one table and update columns data to ID of other table

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am new to mysql

I have two Tables in my database.

1. **id_details_table**

   > CREATE TABLE `id_details_table` (   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,   `CNIC`
   > varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
2. **mobiles_sim_details**

   > CREATE TABLE `mobiles_sim_details` (   `Mobile` double DEFAULT NULL,
   > `CNIC` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,   `id_cnic` int(11) DEFAULT NULL )
   > ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Table 1 column (CNIC) contains values like ('4200004873681') and table 2 also contains the same data in column (CNIC). I want to replace this data in table 2 with the primary key of table 1

I have tried this query but it didn't worked

```
UPDATE `mobiles_sim_details` SET `id_cnic`='[value-3]' WHERE (SELECT id FROM id_details_table WHERE CNIC = mobiles_sim_details.CNIC);
```

How can i Acheive this ?

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Best way to find out would be to Do IT and See what happens

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of checking steps.

Step 1. Ensure that the datatypes of the columns in the tables are allowed for the referencing and are identical completely (for string-type column also check CHARSET/COLLATE). The only allowed difference - the column nullability may differ. Remember that some datatypes cannot be used in the relation - for example, BLOB or JSON,- at all or without length prefix.

Step 2. Ensure that the column on the side "one" is uniquely indexed (it is defined as primary key or unique index by it is present).

Step 3. Ensure that the column on the side "many" does not contain values which are not present in the column on the side "one". Exclusion - NULL values.

If these steps provides positive results then you may create FOREIGN KEY relation with according statement.